# Hystrix run() method executing even after timeout

Tags: hystrix

I created a class by extending HystrixCommand and configured timeout for the request using below code

```
HystrixCommandProperties.Setter().withExecutionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds(int milliSec);
```

Also overriden fallBack method when request not returns response within timeout specified

```
@Override
protected JSONObject run() throws Exception
{
        // performed some http call
        final HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, JSONObject.class)
                .getBody();

        System.out.println(response);
        return response;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject getFallback()
{
    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("status", "900");
    json.put("message", "Request Failed");
    return json;
}
```

Am getting fallBack method response whenever request takes more time than timeout specified which is expected.

But, what I observed is, when timeout occurs fallBack response is getting returned, and the response of the request which is executed in run method is coming later and am not able to hold or return as we returned the fallback response as soon as timeout.

Is there any way I can return that response ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No not possible

Comment: Is it possible to cancel that particular request in fallBack method ??

Comment: Hystrix 'interrupts' the thread and this can be verified in your run method by checking `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`. However `RestTemplate` will not stop when it is in the middle of a blocking IO call so the interrupt will not have any effect on your `run` method. You are already handling failures/timeouts in fallback. Why do you want to stop/cancel the run method?